# What are the limitations on catching pokemon in the Pokemon Dream World?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

I used the [Pokemon Global Link](http://en.pokemon-gl.com/) website for the first time the other day, and I left with a few of my questions about how it works answered but with many more new ones.  I can probably figure most of them out through experimentation, but there was one concern I had above all the rest.

When Fennel was explaining the board inside your house (where you have a picture of the Pokemon  you caught while going over the rainbow bridge), she said something along the lines of "If you have 50 pictures on the board, you can't cross the rainbow bridge any more!"

Does this mean that there is a hard limit of 50 pokemon you can ever catch in the dream world?  Once you catch an aggregate of 50 pokemon over all your visits, you can never catch another?  If not, how do you clear out the board so that you can catch more?

If so, I'm going to be more judicious in which ones I catch and which ones I just pass over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their was originally a 50 pokemon limit in the NA version, but it has [since been removed:](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Dream_World#Updates_and_history)

> At some point in 2010, the limit that meant that players could only ever send 50 Pokémon from the Friend Board was removed.

Comment: I dunno... sounds kind of fishy, but if the limit was 50 only, and if that was a fixed amount then we can say for certain that you Can't catch them all(Imean the people at Gamefreak lied, because Gamefreak won't let you)... Of course, the Japanese players CAN still catch them all as they atre given a specail privilage... I haven't gotten that far yet, but a 50 pokemon limit online seems strange(I mean COME ON!! Only 50?! Sounds like a scam to me... You would think that they would be encouraging gamers to use the online functions) The only way that remains to techincally get them all is to hope

Comment: According to Bulbapedia, the 50 Pokemon limit was removed some time in 2010.

Answer (score 2):

No, you are able to continue to get as many pokemon as you wish. However, you can only store 50 pokemon on the board in the dreamworls. It acts as a pokemon box so once that is full, you will not be able to go to the forest to recruit more friends. What you do, is you send the pokemon from the dream world, over to the entralink, where the pokemon can now be in your black or white copy. However, it is important to note, that eventually you will run out of room, when you have filled all your boxes and the dream world billboard. So only keep pokemon that you really need or want. hopes this helps!

Comment: Hmm, I did upvote this but I think I am missing something. When you go over the rainbow bridge to the island of dreams, you can catch at most 10 Pokemon. Then, when you get to the tree of dreams, you can only choose one Pokemon to send to Entralink. The others disappear. So where does the 50 number come from?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat 50 trips to the island of dreams, catching one pokemon at a time.

Comment: @Strix: sure, but you can't exit the Dream World without sending the Pokemon to Entralink, so there can never be 50 Pokemon waiting to be sent...

Answer (score -1):

You can go to the Friend Board or whatever and uncheck the Pokémon you catch, though, so they won't come with you. This way, you can keep more. It seems very obnoxious, though, so there must be another way.